# Adding a floating view to my app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

My application uses `UITabBarController` to present 3 tabs, each tab has a `UINavigationController` that manag all the view controllers.

What I want to do is to add a view that will be "floating" above all views.

For example suppose I want to show my logo at the top-left corner of the screen, and I want this logo to stay on screen no matter where the user navigates, no matter witch tab he is on.

I suppose I need to add this logo to the `UIWindow`? I just wonder what is the best practice for doing it?

Comment: yes you should try placing it on UIWindow may be it can work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add anything to the Window other than the navigation controller,or root controller. Trust me you will run into memory issues if you do this as Window isnt released but View Controllers are.

Add that floating view to to each view controller and put it as the last item in the list of subviews. You can design it once in IB or progmatically and duplicate it on each screen. This is the approach i always take and your suggested idea doesn't save you any time.

Comment: Seems like adding this view everywhere in the code will consume much more memory and harder to maintain, don't forget that anyway I want this view to stay throughout all the app lifetime, so I have no problem that it wont be released...

Comment: You cant guarantee that adding a view on the window will put it above every other subview too. Trust me the amount of memory you have to play with  this really isn't an issue. I have tried what you are suggesting and it causes problems and isn't the correct approach.

Comment: "You cant guarantee that adding a view on the window will put it above every other subview too..." In what cases a view can be above it?

Comment: When you transition to a new VC using navigation controller for one example. Not to mention the fact that rotation changes might not be sent correctly to those subviews too.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a good place to place it is in the window just when the app launches. E.g.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //...
    //... Setup root View Controller

    UIView *extraView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,20)];
    [extraView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]];    

    [self.window addSubView: extraView];

    return YES;
}
```